# Image Missing From GridView

Tags: android

I have gridview with Imageview and textview the text view is display correctly and the image is take along time to load from the server  and my problem is when I scroll down the image is missing from the gridview I am using volly NetworkImageView to load data from url  and here is my gridview adapter

```
 public class GridViewWordAdapter extends   BaseAdapter {

private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;
private List<Word> movieItems;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridViewWordAdapter(Context context, List<Word> movieItems) {
this.context = context;
this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return movieItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {

TextView textViewItem;
TextView textViewen;
TextView textViewar;
TextView textViewtag;
TextView textViewaudio;
NetworkImageView networkImageView;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)          { 

View gridViewAndroid;

if (convertView == null) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_word_layout, null);
} else {
    gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
}

TextView textViewen = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_en);
TextView textViewar = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_ar);
TextView textViewtag = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_tagoi);
TextView textViewaudio = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_audio);
NetworkImageView networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_word_image);

Word word = movieItems.get(position);

imageLoader =    CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
imageLoader.get(word.getImg(),     ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

networkImageView.setImageUrl(word.getImg(), imageLoader);
textViewen.setText(word.getEnglish());
textViewar.setText(word.getArabic());
textViewtag.setText(word.getTagoi());
textViewaudio.setText(word.getAudio());

return gridViewAndroid;
}
}
```

and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

possible changes you have to made is,
1. You are declaring views in viewholder and  in getview(). Declare them in getview() only.
2. `word.getImg()` should be a valid string url format.
3. Instead of using only R.mipmap.ic_launcher, use its foreground or background image.
4. **after** collected all data, use `yourGridViewName.setAdapter(yourGridAdapterName);`.
hope it helps .

Comment: word.getImg() is a valid url format and here i set adapter to gridview like this 
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter); and I see the image somtimes duplicated and somtimes its show image in its wrong position